# Django: Creating a form per user on one page

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Sorry the title isn't very descriptive. The context: I have an event full of participants. When the event is over I want to leave feedback for all of the other participants.

models.py

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
    action = models.ForeignKey(Action)
    feedback_by = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='feedback_by')
    feedback_for = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='feedback_for')
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    no_show = models.BooleanField()
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    modified = models.DateTimeField()
```

forms.py

```
class FeedbackFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super(FeedbackFormSet, self).add_fields(form, index)
        form.fields['is_checked'] = forms.BooleanField(required=False)  

class FeedbackForm(forms.ModelForm):
    comment = forms.CharField(label=(u"Comment"), widget=forms.Textarea())

    class Meta:
        model = Feedback
        fields = ['comment', 'no_show']
```

I want to create a feedback page, where there would be one instance of the FeedbackForm for each participant. After some searching it seems that to do that I want to be using a FormSet, but I'm not finding the documentation for it very helpful and I can't seem to find any good examples.

If a formset is the way to go, could you guys help me out with some (view/formset basically) starter code? If not, can you point me to what I should be doing? Thanks.

EDIT: I've added my view and template code below.

views.py

```
@login_required
def new_feedback(request, action_id):
    action = get_object_or_404(Action, id=action_id)
    profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)  
    participants = all_info_many_profiles(action.participants.filter(~Q(id=profile.id)))

    fbformset = modelformset_factory(Feedback, form=FeedbackForm, formset=FeedbackFormSet)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = fbformset(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=action.participants.filter(~Q(id=profile.id)))
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
        else:
            print formset.errors
    else:
        formset = fbformset(queryset=action.participants.filter(~Q(id=profile.id)))

    return render(request, 'app/new_feedback.html', 
                 {'action': action, 'participants': participants, 'formset': formset}
```

new_feedback.html

```
{% block body_block %}
<h1>Leave Feedback</h1>  

    {% for participant in participants %}
        <li>{{ participant.username }}</li>
    {% endfor %}

    <form method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in formset %}
            {{ form.as_p }} <br />
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Feedback" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to associate one form to each user in the list (or queryset) of participants. What I currently have shows one more form than I want (for example, when I list each user I'll see 3 names but 4 forms [example](http://i1109.photobucket.com/albums/h427/dakisbac/eg_zpsc2fa22a0.png)) and I don't know if or how the users/forms are related.

The idea is that the feedback_for field will get its value automatically, ie in the view I would do:

```
if formset.is_valid():
    for form in formset:
        a = form.save(commit=false)
        a.feedback = participant
        a.save()
```

On top of that, I added an extra field "is_checked" which is intended to specify whether I'm leaving feedback for that user or not. Example of full functionality:

user1 [X] is_checked
... rest of form

user2 [] is_checked
... rest of form

user3 [X] is_checked
... rest of form

Then when I hit submit it will create two new entries in the Feedback table, one for user1 and one for user3

Comment: What, exactly, is unclear about the documentation for [model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets)? That has example code that shows exactly how to create a set of forms for a queryset.