# Django: Strange Formset behaviour after first submission

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

Long post ahead!

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218979/django-creating-a-form-per-user-on-one-page), which was about creating a feedback page that associates one form to each user. I was able to get that done, but it was done in what I guess is a hacked-together way because I'm seeing some really strange behaviour after I submit feedback one time.

Let's say I've not submitted any feedback previously, and now I want to submit feedback for two of three people ([img](http://i1109.photobucket.com/albums/h427/dakisbac/fb_zps7957f24e.png)). The hidden management_form details appear as follows:

```
<input id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="3" />
<input id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS" name="form-INITIAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="0" />  
<input id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="1000" />
```

On submit this successfully creates two new entries in the Feedback table, as wanted. The problem is that now if I go to any feedback page (as any user) I see the feedback I have already created and I'll get errors on submit.

If I now go to a page with one or two users I'll see one or two forms (this is good) but the management_form data is incorrect. For example, on a one user page I'll see this management_form data:

```
<input id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="3" />
<input id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS" name="form-INITIAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="2" />   
<input id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="1000" />
```

And get this error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /feedback/2/
"u'form-1-id'"
```

Since I'm only supposed to have one form appear that's all I see, and it's set to the first of the two feedbacks already created, but there's obviously a problem with the management data. Initial should be 0 (not 2) and total forms should be 1 (not 3).

If I go to a page with an equal number of users I'll see the original three feedback forms, with this management_form data:

```
<input id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="5" />
<input id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS" name="form-INITIAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="2" />
<input id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="1000" />
```

Again, total should be 3 (not 5) and initial should be 0 (not 2). This time I don't get an error though, because I'll get a message saying that I need to fill in values for two forms which don't even appear on the page.

Hopefully that explains the problem well enough, so here's the code:

models.py

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
    action = models.ForeignKey(Action)
    feedback = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    feedback_by = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='feedback_by')
    feedback_for = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='feedback_for')
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    modified = models.DateTimeField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        if not self.id:
            self.created = datetime.datetime.today()
        self.modified = datetime.datetime.today()

        return super(Feedback, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

forms.py

```
class FeedbackForm(forms.ModelForm):
    choices = (('g', '(+1) Positive'),
               ('b', '(±0) Negative'),
               ('n', '(-1) No Show'),
               ('d', 'Don\'t Leave Feedback'))
    feedback = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=choices, initial='d')
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())

    class Meta:
        model = Feedback
        fields = ['feedback_for','feedback','comment']
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def new_feedback(request, action_id):

    action = get_object_or_404(Action, id=action_id)
    profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)  
    participants = all_info_many_profiles(action.participants.filter(~Q(id=profile.id)))

    fbformset = modelformset_factory(Feedback, form=FeedbackForm, extra=len(participants))

    if request.method == 'POST':    
        formset = fbformset(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            #formset.save(commit=False)
            for form in formset:
                tmp = form.save(commit=False)
                tmp.action = action
                tmp.feedback_by = profile
                if tmp.feedback != 'd':
                    tmp.save()
            return index(request)
        else:
            print formset.errors
            #return index(request)        
    else:
        formset = fbformset()

    return render(request, 'app/new_feedback.html', 
                  {'action': action, 'participants': participants, 'formset': formset}
                  )
```

feedback.html

```
{% load multifor %}
{% block body_block %}
    <h1>Leave Feedback</h1>  

    <form method="post" action="{% url 'app:new_feedback' action.id%}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% comment %}
        <input id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="{{participants.count}}" />
        <input id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS" name="form-INITIAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="0" />
        <input id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="1000" />
        {% endcomment %}
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        {{ formset.errors }}
        {% for form in formset; participant in participants %}
            {{ form.id }}
            {{ form.errors }}
            <input id="id_form-{{forloop.counter0}}-feedback_for" name="form-{{forloop.counter0}}-feedback_for" type="hidden" value="{{participant.id}}" /> <br />
            {{ form.feedback_for.label }} {{ participant.username }}: <br />
            {% for radio in form.feedback %}
                {{ radio }} <br />
            {% endfor %}<br />
            {{ form.comment.label }} {{ form.comment }} <br /><br />
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Feedback" />
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a modelformset_factory, this factory is tied to the model and it will "help" you by populating stuff, [this is why the count is at 5](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L560).

You might get the result you want by using a plain [formset_factory](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/formsets.py#L413). Django's docs has [some examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/formsets/#django.forms.formsets.BaseFormSet)

Comment: That was it. So simple...

To be quite honest, even after reading the docs I'm not sure why I was using modelformset. Originally I was trying to send initial values using queryset= and initial= and I wasn't really getting anywhere.

So my follow-up question would be: what is the purpose of modelformset vs formset?

Comment: It is quite useful actually, django's admin is the best example, all the inlines are modelformsets so that you can edit existing entities and create new ones.